# How to replicate domains from different forests

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, replication

I have 2 domains each in a different forest with transitive trust... Now, I am asked to do replication between them. My question is.. is that possible? if so how can I do that? any clue?
I've made replication between domains from the same forest before but now I havent be able to find any info about that...

Comment: `I am asked to do replication between them` - Do you mean replicate the AD? If so, that's not possible.

Comment: In addition to defining what you mean by "replicate" what is the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes.. I mean replicate the AD database.. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure replication between domains in different forests.

If you need to duplicate the objects, use something like ldifde.exe for a one-time export or Microsoft Identity Manager for ongoing synchronization.